# Obfuscate Windows Phone 8 dll

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to obfuscate a Windows Phone 8 dll.

I tried the "PreEmptive Dotfuscator" available in Visual Studio 2012. I added the .dll But it fails.

Is there any other free tool to obfuscate?

Thanks
SRS

Comment: What did you do? how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try DeepSea Obfuscator (version over 4.3), which works fine for me.
Visit http://www.deepseaobfuscator.com/home.aspx